# Generate Sound and Record Audio parallely using Threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, audio

So basically, I am making an application which at the touch of a button generates a sound for 1 second after every 10 seconds and simultaneously records all other sounds as well.

I want the sound recording to happen in that 10 second pause. I tried to use threads and thread interrupts for this. But don't really know how to use them properly for this case.

Here is my code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    playButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
           // Sound Gen Thread
            Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                       public void run() {
                            AudioTrack tone = generateTone(freq, 1000);
                            tone.play();
                        }
                    }, 0, 10000);
                }
            };
            new Thread(myRunnable).start();

            //Recording Thread

            Runnable myRunnable1 = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doInBackground();
                }
            };
            new Thread(myRunnable1).start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you want to do so infinitely or just a few number of times.

Comment: I want to do so infinitely. It should keep going on till the app is manually closed.

Comment: Try something like this....  https://jpst.it/UDWX .Just wanted to simulate the conditions before actually trying it in Android. Let me know if you face any problem in understanding the code.